# valley construction with cedar roof on skip sheathing

Tags: roof

Is it considered best practice to put solid decking beneath valleys when installing cedar on skip sheathing?

Comment: What sort of valley? Steel?

Comment: Undecided at present. enameled steel is a possibility, but so is copper.